# How to create and validate forms in Javascript / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm currently developing a checkout form for an e-commerce site, as any other checkout there are a lot of validations on its fields, things like:

- If the user selects the radio buton 'I'm Company' show the VAT field.
- If the user has no billing address show the inputs to create a new shipping address.
- If the user has billing addresses list them as radio buttons.

And a lot more, currently I'm using thinks like `addClass('hide')` or `removeClass('hide')`, in other cases I use `toggle()`, it works but somehow I feel that this is not a solid approach.

Is there any 'Best Practices' to create forms and validate them?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Jquery validation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/). It will you give you flexiblity and easy to use.